# Scala/Java servlets: How to output < in the HTML code instead of &lt;

Tags: java, html, scala, servlets

I have a servlet coded in Scala. I have some code like this in there:

```
def message = <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Test</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>{value}</BODY></HTML>
def value = "Hello <BR/> World"
```

The corresponding HTML code generated for `value` is

```
Hello &lt;BR/&gt; World
```

How do I get it to generate the HTML code (shown below)?

```
Hello <BR/> World
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don’t mind changing the type of `value` to `xml.Elem`, you can do

```
def value = <xml:group>Hello <BR/> World</xml:group>
```

**Addition**

In my opinion, you should type as much XML inline as possible. Only then will you have compile time validation of the input. All other solutions either give you a runtime exception at some point (say, you forgot some `/`) or might even break your XML layout.

However, if you really want to have an easy transform, you could do this:

```
class XmlString(str: String) {
  def assumeXML = xml.XML.loadString("<xml:group>" + str + "</xml:group>")
  def toUnparsedXML = new xml.Unparsed(str)
}
implicit def stringToXmlString(str: String) = new XmlString(str)

def value = "Hello <BR/> World"
```

and then (for some reason, it still shows the `<xml:group>` part; you could get rid of it with `xml.NodeSeq.fromSeq(value.assumeXML.child)` or similar)

```
def message = <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Test</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>{value.assumeXML}</BODY></HTML>
```

or even (well, you would not need the implicit here, `Unparsed(value)` would do)

```
def message = <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Test</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>{value.toUnparsedXML}</BODY></HTML>
```

The `assumeXML` method will fail with at runtime, if you provide invalid XML; `toUnparsedXML` will accept all input, even data that is potentially dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping there was an easier way. However,  in the end, keeping it as `xml.Elem` makes more sense, though it involved a bit of code-changing.